# Spring Outbound SFTP integration streaming

Tags: java, sftp, spring-integration-sftp, low-memory

We are developing a spring batch application which is going to process "big" files in the future. To maintain a low memory signature we use spring batch on the smallest possible chunks of these files.
After processing, we want to write a result back to `SFTP`, which also happens per chunk of the input file.

The current approach is as follows:

`StepExecutionListener.before()`: we send a message to the `SftpOutboundAdapter` with `FileExistsMode.REPLACE` and empty payload to create an empty file (with `.writing`)

`Reader`: will read the input file

`Processor`: will enhance the input with the results and return a list of string

`Writer`: will send the list of strings to another `SftpOutboundAdapter` with `FileExistsMode.APPEND`

`StepExecutionListener.after()`: In case the execution as successful we will rename the file to remove the `.writing` suffix.

Now I saw that there are `Streaming Inbound Adapters` but I could not find `Streaming Outbound Adapters`. 
Is this really the only/best way to solve it by append? Or is it possible to stream the file content?